# Efficient java library for text templating?

Tags: java, templates, text, template-engine

I've got a simple `string` coming in from a UI component as `The device id is %{test}`. Assume **%{test}** is a dynamic variable and the values for it are being assigned from the backend code. The final `string` should look like:

```
The device id is some text
```

----------------------------^ should be replaced with `%{test}` and appended to the whole string

I've read a bit and tried out some of the libraries which were pointed out [here](https://java-source.net/open-source/template-engines), such as *Velocity* and *FreeMarker*. But I'm quite unaware in terms of efficiency and performance on using those libraries.

Hope I could get some insights on this since I'm pretty new to this. Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Any notes for the downvote, so that I could improve my question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but asking for libraries (and recommendations) is generally speaking off-topic. Also performance questions are often a tricky topic anyway.

Comment: @UnholySheep I've got somewhat knowledge on the libraries available, just that I'm not sure whether I'm heading towards the right path, since performance is a major consideration. Thanks for the point out.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at [Arco](http://arco.samajackun.com/arco-maven-plugin/faq.html) Template Engine: It compiles the template in compile-time, producing a .java (or .class) file. And so, at run-time, the expansion is done very fast.

The templates should be coded in JSP format. Thus, all variables references must be written `${variable}` (not `%{variable}`).

The only thing to take in account is that templates must be *staticly* generated (in order to be processed at compile-time).

(Read the FAQ and the examples).

Comment: Thank you for the assist. I'll have a look and get back to you :)